# Multiple iterations or complicated code?

Tags: performance, loops, iteration

I've run into this problem a number of times already. Say I iterate over a list and I'd like to "look" at it in different ways (the list's data can be interpreted differently depending on the way you parse it). This could be done in one iteration only, but the code would look messy and complicated. The other way is to iterate over the list multiple times; once for each task. I'd go with this, but what if the list is very large and each iteration would be costly performance-wise?
So, to summarize, is it better to:

**a) iterate and handle everything at once

b) perform multiple iterations and handle only one task each iteration**

I'm looking forward to hearing your answers.

Comment: Do __a__, and wrap each of the tasks into standalone function/module that only does something to the unit item of the list for better structure, and make sure objects are not mutated unexpectedly. This question is pretty vague without sample code, and without a language specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The answer is "it depends".

First of all, I notice you don't specify an architecture. For example, it makes a lot of difference if you do stuff on a GPU or on a CPU - and similarly a different CPU will also work differently. For now I'll assume an Intel CPU for simplicity, but do keep this in mind.

You marked this question with the tag "performance", so that's how I will interpret this question. As for performance, there's only one golden standard, and that is that a benchmark will tell you the truth. That said, there are some guidelines to keep in mind:

- Sequential data access is better than random access. This has everything to do with the way things like the memory model and vectorization works.
- Unpredictable branching can potentially kill your performance. Usually this happens when you make a single monolytic function that does everything.
- If you can process small blocks of memory (say, <= 4K) in an "iteration", that's usually faster because it means you keep working from your cache. If you have to process a lot, you might want to write a testcase first to benchmark.

Personally I think that the video's of Mike Acton tell a lot about how to write proper high performance code. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rX0ItVEVjHc and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPpD4BBtA1Y are the most important video's to watch (they really are worth the time if you ask me).

Answer (score 1):

This is a trade-off between code quality and performance. No general answer can be given. Both choices are valid depending on the requirements.